# `Bad stdio forwarding specification '%h:%p'` appears by ssh option but it does not appear by ~/.ssh/config

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

I wrote forwarding settings below in`~/.ssh/config` and `ssh destination` works well (successfully logged in to `destination`):

```
Host gateway
  User ikuwow
  Hostname gateway.example.com

Host destination
  User ikuwow
  Hostname destination.localname
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p gateway
```

But the command below returns error:

```
$ ssh -oProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p gateway' ikuwow@destination.localname
Bad stdio forwarding specification '%h:%p'
```

ssh version (macOS High Sierra):

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.5p1, LibreSSL 2.5.4
```

What is the difference between these settings?
How can I `ssh` through bastions using the `-oProxyCommand` option?

Comment: I've just opened a similar question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/887924/ssh-with-a-bastion-host-stdio-forwarding-failed

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's still actual for u, but this trick works well in an older manner:

```
Host 172.16.*.*
  ProxyCommand ssh gateway_server nc %h %p
```