# SSH with a Bastion Host - stdio forwarding failed

Tags: ssh, proxy

I'm setting up a Bastion Host on AWS (some details here: https://www.nadeau.tv/ssh-with-a-bastion-host/), to allow me secure access to my other EC2 instances I have on AWS.

I'm running into a few issues when trying to proxy through the bastion host.

My SSH Config file is follows:

```
# Bastion Host
Host bastion
User ec2-user
Hostname XX.XX.XX.XXX
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/bastion.pem

# EC2 Instance
Host 172.*
User ec2-user
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/bastion.pem
ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W %h:%p
```

Below is the verbose output from the command line:

```
Jeff-Bezos-iMac:tmp jeff$ ssh 172.xx.x.xx -v
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/jeff/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/jeff/.ssh/config line 9: Applying options for 172.*
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh bastion -W 172.xx.x.xx:22
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jeff/.ssh/keys/bastion.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jeff/.ssh/keys/bastion.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 503
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I'm stuck, getting an error 'stdio forwarding failed', any help appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have SSH security group configured correctly, when it was changed to accept incoming SSH requests from the Bastion Server's private IP, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Can you share details of what you did?  I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @Jonathan might be too late but you might need to add Hostname in your ~/.ssh/config file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the Bastion/Jumpbox host was not able to resolve the Hostname (I used hostnames and not IP), so in my case that was a bad DNS entry in my DNS setup, so just make sure the Bastion host can resolve to the same name you are using in your ssh config file.

Answer (score 0):

I set `AllowTcpForwarding yes` at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in the Bastion Host, restarted `sshd` (`systemctl restart sshd.service`) and it solved a connection problem for me.